# append object to an item of json file without fs.readFile in node,js

Tags: node.js, json, object

i have a json file. like below

```
{
  "key": [],
  "record": []
}
```

I want to add some object to the empty items key,and record,like below

```
   {
     "key": [
              {
                  "keyPressed": "5",
                  "PressTime": "Tue Jan 05 2021 18:05:43 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)",
                  "filePlaying": "",
                   "PlayBackDuration": ""
                 }
                 ],

             "record":[]
                }
```

I am using jsonFile module in nodejs to create the initial json file.I also want to use jsonFile to append/add object to items. as jsonFile help to reduce the effort of opening,stringify and write back to file.
do I have to do it manually or there is any option like below. is there a simpler way ?

```
key.push( { "xx" : "yy } )
```

Comment: You can look at JSON lines: https://jsonlines.org/

Comment: If you have your object in a Variable then you can push directly to your array `key.push(your_object)`

Comment: its in a file like info.json... @Jagveer